# 1-dimensional representations of Lie groups

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

In physics people often talk about the singlet representation **1** of a Lie group, meaning the 1-dimensional trivial representation, which maps everything to the identity.

Sometimes it seems to me that people assume that any 1-dimensional representation is the trivial one. This fact is true for SU(2), and my question is:

```
    Under what conditions does a Lie group only have one 1-dimensional representation?
```

My working so far:

If $G$ is Lie group and $R: G \to GL(1;\mathbb{C}) \cong U(1) $ a representation, which we will define to be a smooth group homomorphism, then the commutator subgroup of $G$ is mapped to the identity. So a relevant question is:

```
    Under what conditions do the commutators of a Lie group generate the whole group?
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: One says a group is *perfect* if its commutators generate it. Simple groups are perfect, and there is not a lot more that one can say, really.

Comment: Thanks! What about the converse? Do all non-simple Lie groups have a quotient into $U(1)$ ?